# Adding worksheet to the excel file selected by user

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer, activex

I am using ActiveX object to add worksheet to the user selected excel file. With the below code its working. ( This is a IE fix, so using ActiveX )

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
  var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(path); 
  var ws = excel_file.Worksheets;
  resultSheet = ws.Add();
```

But created worksheet is adding at first, I want to add it after the existing sheets in the excel. Is it possible ? What parameters should I pass it to Add method ?

Comment: In `VBA` you would use `After` to add after the lasy existing sheet, so `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add , Sheets(Sheets.Count)`. You presumably need the javascript equivalent for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think brettdj had the gist of it, try:

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(path); 
var ws = excel_file.Worksheets;
resultSheet = ws.Add(null,ws(ws.Count));
```

Comment: Here's the args for [`Worksheets.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.add)